# Removing double quotations marks from String in Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas

i am currently looping through a subset of a Pandas DataFrame and the string values inside have double quotation marks surrounding them. If i don't get them removed, i won't be able to compare them to what i need them compared to.

This is the code i have so far:

```py
df_asinn = df.copy()
for index, screen_name in df.loc[:, ["username"]].iterrows():
    user_tweet_list = []
    screen_name[0] = screen_name[0].strip()
    stripped_screen_name = screen_name[0].strip()
```

The value varaible containing the string value in screen_name[0]. I have ried multiple things, with no prevail. I tried using screen_name.strip(), which did not work. I tried to use .translate('"'), however, this did also not work. It would be great if anyone had a solution to the problem.

Te goal is from having the list strings looking like this

```
"String1",
"String2",
"String3"
```

To looking like this:

```
String1,
String2,
String3
```

I know its supposed to look like that, because if i do print("String1"), the output is:

```
String1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure exactly what you're getting at: see comment by @Panda Kim. However, two things that might point you in the right direction:

1. Calling `string.replace(char, '')` will replace all instances of `char` in `string` with a blank string, effectively removing them. I usually use this method, though `translate` works well too. It seems, though, that the proper call is `translate(None, char)`.
2. By calling the str method on a column (`df[col_name].str`), you can call any string function and it will apply that function to allelements in the column. For instance, calling `df['screen name'].str.replace('\"', '')` will give the same result as looping through `df['screen name']` and calling `replace` on each element.